# google play services default notifications

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been developing a game using the google play games TurnBasedMultiplayer API but I can't find a way to replace the default push notifications that the API sends to a player when he/she receieves a move/invitation. The default notification takes me to google play games, I would love to override that or remove it completely and add my own custom soloution.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To disable the notification for turn that is sent by the Google Play:

Quoting from the official Docs:

***Your game can call takeTurn() with the current player as the pending participant. In this case, Google Play games services uploads the game data but no notification is sent.***

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. This does indeed stop notifications; however, only the active participant can modify a game so I'd be left with a 1 player turn based game.